# Why doesn't PyCharm show me type hint validation errors

Tags: python, types, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 2021.2.2 (Community Edition). I'm learning about [Python Type Hints from the FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/). When I write a function like this

```
def get_name_with_age(name: str, age: int) -> str:
    name_with_age = name + " is this old: " + age
    return 10
```

[Shouldn't Pycharm warn me](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html) that I'm attempting to return an int but the function is supposed to return a string? And / or shouldn't it warn me that I can't concatenate a string with an int? Pycharm doesn't warn me about either of these things..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was in "power save" mode. Once disabled this, type hint validation started working.